# How to do a one-line WRITE in fortran

Tags: fortran

Fortran newbie here.  If I have doubles TIME and Y, and I want to output them to a file with unit unitid, but I want to shorten the format of the doubles, can I do this in one line? what i have below doesn't work since it defaults to format for the doubles that is too long.

```
WRITE(unitid,*) 'TIME:',TIME, 'Y:', Y;
```

Note that i am using a fortran library so formatted output using a FORMAT statement doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: `WRITE(unitid,'(2(a,f10.3))') 'TIME:',TIME, 'Y:', Y;`

Comment: WRITE(unitid,'(2(a,f10.3))') 'TIME:',TIME, 'Y:', Y;
          X
 THE CHARACTERS IN ERROR ARE: '
  34  INTEGER VALUE IS REQUIRED FOR THIS OPTION.

Comment: Show more code, see [mcve]. How do you declare `unitid`? Edit the question with more informarion, don't use comments.

Comment: Why the ";" at the end of the line?  The error message ("... IS REQUIRED FOR THIS OPTION") indicates something wrong with your invocation of the FORTRAN compiler or interpreter and not the WRITE statement itself.  Please post the entire program unit and invocation command.